# Native C++ Systray application questions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, system-tray

I have been writing a program to ping three different sites and then it informs the user if they have internet or not.

I have had a lot of success on getting this program to work, in no small part due to the awesomeness of the community here.

My code is written in native c++ due to the fact that I know the language the best. What I am hoping for is for the community to point me in the direction getting my program to run in the system tray without using .net programming.

I am using Visual studio 2008 and I have got my code to install using the setup project. I would be grateful to any help that you guys can show me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native C++ systray applications are based on the Win32 Shell API [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx).

To add your icon to the sys tray you want something like this:

```
memset(&iconData, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
iconData.hIcon = ::LoadIcon(hResourceModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME));
iconData.hIcon = ::LoadIcon(hResourceModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));
iconData.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
iconData.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
iconData.hWnd = this->m_hWnd;
strncpy(iconData.szTip, programTitle_buffer, programTitle_length);
if(iconData.hIcon)
{
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &iconData);
}
```

To remove your icon you want something like this:

```
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &iconData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SysTray_Application.aspx) with a more tutorial-like approach than the Win32 docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in C++, you would have to use windows low level api like just mentioned by Zildjohn01 . It isn't that hard. You can always have a look at this old code project post: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/shell/systemtray.aspx